# Get facebook comments from fan page post/update

Tags: facebook, comments

When I create a new item it is posted to a fan page (http://www.facebook.com/pages/stadsklassen/101802476536649?sk=wall) and I get the postid as reponse which I store in the database next to the new created item.

I would like to display the comments from each individual post from the fan page on the correct page on my website using the postid I stored in the database but it doesn't work.

This is the code I have that should be displaying the comments:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=APP_ID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments xid="<?php echo FAN_PAGE_POST_ID; ?>" numposts="10" width="600" publish_feed="true">
</fb:comments>
```

I thought I could do this with the xid but apparently it just creates a new unique id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FAN_PAGE_POST_ID` is **NOT** the `xid`, have a look at the [`comment`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) table. I suggest you query this table with the `FAN_PAGE_POST_ID` as your `post_id` to check if you can get the `xid`.

P.S: I don't *think* what you are trying to do is possible as I've never seen it.

Comment: I did and it did not have an xid, I also used the graph API. however this plugin claims it can do what i'm looking for -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-shared-comments/ or is it not possible anymore because facebook changed their API?

Comment: @krike: it seems this plugin only adds the Facebook Comment plugin to the comments section.

Comment: just guessing here but is it possible to create an xid when posting to facebook? If this is possible can I then use that xid to get the facebook comments?